# set up an action with a tab bar item - iphone

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, action, uitabbaritem

I don't no if this is possible, but this there a way to treat a tab bar item click like a regular button click(action)? Here's the reason: I have a tab bar in my application, and for most of the tab bar items, I don't change the screen upon a touch, but I do change the data displayed in the view. It seems that it would be going a bit overboard to use a TabBarAppDelegate for this...is there a better way?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The most straightforward way is the UITabBarDelegate. Sorry. Implement your class and inherit the protocol by adding `<UITabBarDelegate>` after your class definition e.g.:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController<UITabBarDelegate>
```

and then define the method `tabBar:didSelectItem:` in that class e.g.

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item {
    // Do Stuff!
    // if(item.title == @"First") {...}
}
```

Then set the delegate on your tabbar like so: `myTabBar.delegate = myClassInstance`. The `tabBar:didSelectItem:` method can be anywhere including your view controller and is where you will get the event that the button was clicked. More info here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Got it. Thanks! Also this is a good reference I found: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2099944?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I would use [`UISegmentedControl`](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html) and place it in a [`UIToolbar`](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIToolbar_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or [`UINavigationBar`](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html).  That way you get the same touch-to-change-data effect, but don't have to swap view controllers (or try to bypass switching tabs)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest going with a UIToolbar. Or make your own custom UIView and design it to your liking