# How would I create a slide menu on a Tab Bar Button tap (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, tabbar

I am using the SWRevealViewController library and have set my respective views to 'sw_rear' and 'sw_front'. I know how to create a side menu if it was activated by a bar button item tap as such:

```
menuButton.target = self.revealViewController() 
menuButton.action = "revealToggle:"
```

I am trying to implement a version where the user taps the very right tab bar item and the side menu appears.

I dont know how to set a target and action for this to happen though.

Comment: same way you did it with the menuButton.. just add a target and action to the right tab bar item as self.revealViewController() and "revealToggle:"

Comment: You can't add action to a tab bar item.
Maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575430/set-up-an-action-with-a-tab-bar-item-iphone

Comment: I tried using the tabBar method didSelectItem but there are no properties of the tabBar item to add a target and action

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `UITabBar`, I used `UIToolBar` to achieve this. I placed bar button items on `UIToolBar` and called these methods.

```
//for right most bar button item
menuButton.target = self.revealViewController() 
menuButton.action = "rightRevealToggle:"
```