# How can I have a function called on tabBar Button press but only if the view is currently the one being pressed?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I'm trying to implement a feature similar to facebook and the reddit app so that when I press the news feed button while viewing the news feed it scrolls to the top. However when I press the news feed button from another tab it simply loads the cached state of the view controller.
I want to have a similar feature where pressing the tab bar item associated with the current view active calls a function.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this? [set up an action with a tab bar item - iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575430/set-up-an-action-with-a-tab-bar-item-iphone)
Then put your re-loading code within that didSelectItem method.

Answer (score 0):

So after doing some testing I found out that the delegate call to `UITabBarControllerDelegate occurs in between`viewWillAppear`and`viewDidAppear`so I simply set a boolean value to false in`viewWillAppear`and change it in`viewDidAppear`.